# $rootScope:infdig error with random number in template

Tags: angularjs

### Unable to display AngularJS function return value on the page template

I am dosing some static display on my page involving some basic generation of random data. When I am doing the console log it returns my expected value but when I add the 'return' keyword I have this kind of error.

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

Heres my code.

```
//static seed data
generateRandomSortNumber() {
    //return Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
    console.log(Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1));
}

generateRandomQuestionType() {
    //return this.staticRandomQuestionType[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.staticRandomQuestionType.length)];
    console.log(this.staticRandomQuestionType[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.staticRandomQuestionType.length)]);
}
```

Template part:

```
 <td class="text-left">{{ $ctrl.generateRandomSortNumber() }}</td>
 <td class="text-left">{{ $ctrl.generateRandomQuestionType() }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a scope variable and assign the number instead of calling a function.

```
this.randomNo = Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
```

html

```
<td class="text-left">{{ $ctrl.randomNo  }}</td>
```

Comment: I think that's method will result to 1 number per row only.. I am generating the random differently on every row. But I will try that also. Thanks.